# Find the value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\left(\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: integration, limits

> Find the value of the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

I can't solve the integral $\int_0^1 \mathrm{\frac{1}{1+x^n}}\,\mathrm{d}x$. But maybe the questions doesn't require solving the integral. 
Apparently the $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\int_0^1 \mathrm{\frac{1}{1+x^n}}\,\mathrm{d}x)^n$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$ for the question to make sense. That's all I know.

Comment: Answer should be $-0.5$ i think

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Archis, the answer I obtained is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}$.

Comment: You are right .!

Comment: a solution using probalistic concepts would be really nice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $I(n)$ be given by the integral

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n}\,dx \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Then, expanding the integrand of the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ in the Taylor series $ \frac{1}{1+x^n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{nk}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{nk+1}\\\\
&=1+\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1/n} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

Next, using the fact that $\log(2)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ and that $\frac{\pi^2}{12}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}$, we can write the series in $(2)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1/n} &=-\log(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{k+1/n}-\frac1k\right)\\\\
&=-\log(2)-\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1/n)}\\\\
&=-\log(2)-\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{k(k+1/n)}-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\\\\
&=-\log(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{12n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right) \tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

Using $(1)-(3)$ yields

$$I(n)=1-\frac{\log(2)}{n}+\frac{\pi^2}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right) \tag 4$$

---

Next, using $(4)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(I(n)\right)^n&=e^{n\log\left(1-\frac{\log(2)}{n}+\frac{\pi^2}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{-\log(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{12n}-\frac{\log^2(2)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}\\\\
&=\frac12 \left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{12n}-\frac{\log^2(2)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Finally, we have

> $$\begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n\left(\left(I(n)\right)^n-\frac12\right)\right)&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\log^2(2)}{4}+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\\\\
> &=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\log^2(2)}{4}}
> \end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: exzellent! (+1)

Comment: @tired Thank you!  Much appreciative.

Comment: You have a typo - the result is $\frac{\pi^2}{24} - \frac12 \log^2{2} $.  Otherwise, what I did.

Comment: @RonGordon Yes; good catch.  And the coefficient on $\log^2(2)$ is actually $\frac14$.

Comment: You seem to have used Abel's Thm in showing $I(n)$ equals that series.

Comment: @zhw. The DCT is a quick way to go here.

Comment: I don't see the DCT argument.

Comment: @zhw. I didn't embed the argument in the solution.  I believe that the legitimacy is well known.  -Mark

Comment: The legitimacy of what, the result or the DCT argument? It's the latter I question (and I doubt it works). The result is fine by Abel's theorem. But that is worth pointing out for sure.

Comment: @zhw. $$\left|\frac{1-(-x^n)^{K+1}}{1+x^n}\right| \le \frac{2}{1+x^n}$$This gives an integrable dominating function independent of $K$.  The DCT applies.

Comment: Dr. what you need is $|\sum_{k=0}^{K}(-1)^kx^{nk} - 1/(1+x^n)|$ is dominated by some $g\in L^1(0,1),$ independent of $K.$

Comment: @zhw. We wish to know if $$\lim_{K\to \infty}\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^K (-x^n)^k=\lim_{K\to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{1-(-x^n)^{K+1}}{1+x^n}\,dx=\int_0^1 \lim_{K\to \infty}\frac{1-(-x^n)^{K+1}}{1+x^n}\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^n}\,dx$$To apply the DCT, we need to find an integrable dominating function $f(x;n)$ such that $$\left|\frac{1-(-x^n)^{K+1}}{1+x^n} \right|\le f(x;n)$$Certainly, $f(x;n)=\frac{2}{1+x^n}$ qualifies as such.

Comment: !!!! Finally stupid me can see you are right. I learned $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}/n = \ln 2$ from Abel decades ago, and I've always thought you needed Abel here. Didn't know this. Thank you for your patience. I learned something new. +1

Comment: @zhw. Well, first of all, you are not stupid.  In fact, I've been highly impressed with your knowledge and expertise. I've even wondered whether you're a professor or a high-level graduate student.  In any case, thank you for putting a second pair of eyes on things.  And I'm really pleased that I was "able" to help ... pun intended.

Comment: Former professor, left academia a while back to do other things. I like to keep my hand in the game, so I come to MSE. My comments here were a case of "I know I'm right" without bothering to entertain the idea I could be mistaken - until my boat sank.

Comment: @zhw. I am also a former professor (electromagnetic field theory, a branch of mathematical physics) and left academia in 1996 to pursue a career in financial derivatives trading.  No worry about your comments.  It forced me to post the justification in the comment, which might be useful to others.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV: Instructive and concise derivation! ... and nice comment! ( +1)

Comment: @markusscheur Thank you Markus.  Much appreciative.  -Mark

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. [*If one knows the digamma function $\psi=\Gamma'/\Gamma$*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations), one may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^n}\:dx&=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x^{2n}}\:dx
\\\\&\stackrel{u=x^{2n}}=\frac1{2n}\int_0^1\frac{(1-u^{1/2})u^{1/(2n)-1}}{1-u}\:du
\\\\&=\frac1{2n}\left[\psi\left(\frac1{2n}+\frac12 \right)-\psi\left(\frac1{2n} \right) \right]
\\\\&=1-\frac{\ln 2}{n}+\frac{\pi ^2-6 \ln^2 2}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
n\ln \left(1-\frac{\ln 2}{n}+\frac{\pi ^2-6 \ln^2 2}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)=-\ln 2+\frac{\pi ^2-6 \ln^2 2}{24n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$ 
that is

> $$
> n\left[\left(\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^n}\:dx \right)^n-\frac12\right]\to \frac{\pi ^2-6 \ln^2 2}{24}.
> $$

Comment: Olivier, I obtained a different result by retaining the second order terms.   I don't believe that this is correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you! was busy with something else, edited.

Comment: You're welcome Olivier.  - Mark

Answer (score 5):

My approach is a little different.  I would sub $x=u^{1/n}$ in the integral and get

$$I(n) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^n} = \frac1n \int_0^1 du \frac{u^{\frac1n-1}}{1+u} = \frac1n \int_0^1 du \, u^{1/n} \left (\frac1u - \frac1{1+u} \right ) \\= 1-\frac1n \int_0^1 du \frac{u^{1/n}}{1+u}$$

We then note that $u^{1/n} = e^{\log{u}/n}$ and that $n$ is large enough for the following series expansion to be valid:

$$I(n) = 1- \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{j+1}} \int_0^1 du \frac{\log^j{u}}{1+u} $$

Due to the nature of the limit we are posed, we go out to second order; thus

$$I(n) = 1-\frac{\log{2}}{n} + \frac{\pi^2}{12 n^2} +O \left ( \frac1{n^3} \right ) $$

Then

$$\begin{align}I(n)^n &= e^{n \log{\left [1-\frac{\log{2}}{n} + \frac{\pi^2}{12 n^2} +O \left ( \frac1{n^3} \right )\right ]} } \\ &= e^{n\left [-\frac{\log{2}}{n} + \frac{\pi^2}{12 n^2} - \frac{\log^2{2}}{2 n^2}+O \left ( \frac1{n^3} \right ) \right ] } \\ &= \frac12 \left [1+\left (\frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac12 \log^2{2} \right ) \frac1n +O \left ( \frac1{n^2} \right ) \right ]\end{align}$$

The sought after limit is then

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left [I(n)^n-\frac12 \right ] = \frac{\pi^2}{24} - \frac14 \log^2{2} $$

Comment: Ron, this is a nice alternative solution. +1 ...  -Mark.  P.S.  You might consider adding the methodology used to evaluate the integrals $\int_0^1 \frac{\log^j(u)}{1+u}\,du$ for $j=1,2$.

Comment: nice answer, maybe the $n^{-2}$ coefficient needs a little explanation?

Comment: @Ron Nice answer! (+1)

Comment: @tired: expand the log to second order, i.e. $\log{(1-z)} = -z-z^2/2-O(z^3)$, where $z$ is a binomial.  The first term is used in both the first and second order; the second term is used only in the first order.

Comment: @RonGordon, thanks...