# Compute $ \int_0^1\frac{{\rm d}x}{1+x^n} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I_n := \int_0^1\frac{{\rm d}x}{1+x^n} $$

It doesn't seem elementary to me. How do I solve this?

---

<sub>Related: [Show that $\int_0^ \infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx= \frac{ \pi /n}{\sin(\pi /n)}$ , where $n$ is a positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247866/show-that-int-0-infty-frac11xn-dx-frac-pi-n-sin-pi-n-wh)</sub>

Comment: thanks.but can I change It from 0 to 1?will It be other methods to solve this?thanks for answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asymptotic expansion of $I_n=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015233/562589)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\left(\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015233/562589) (Note: solutions here include parts which might clear your doubt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\left(\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^n-\frac{1}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015233/find-the-value-of-lim-limits-n-to-inftyn-left-left-int-01-frac11xn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you already know, it is a simple or difficult problem. One thing you could consider is that
$$\frac 1 {1+x^n}=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {x-r_k}$$ where the $r_k$'s are the roots of unity.

Now, using partial fraction decomposition, you will have
$$\frac 1 {1+x^n}=\sum_{k=1}^n   \frac {a_k} {x-r_k}$$ which is easy to integrate, leading to
$$\int_0^1 \frac {dx} {1+x^n}=\sum_{k=1}^n    {a_k} \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r_k}\right)$$ This not really funny since the $r_k$ and the $a_k$ are complex numbers.

Now, this integral is in fact (do not worry, you will learn it soon)
$$I_n=\frac{\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2 n}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2
   n}\right)}{2 n}$$ where appears the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

When $n$ is large
$$I_n =1+\frac{\gamma +\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 n}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ with $\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-1.96351$